# Module hook to add_js to any entity type?

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

I want a hook that will let me conditionally add js/css to the page depending on the type of entity.

Since I am putting this in a module I cannot use a theme hook (because if the theme already defines the hook then Drupal will crash).

Ultimately, I want to do something like:

```
// SWTICH BY ENTITY TYPE
switch($entity_type){
    case 'eform':  // entity forms
        drupal_add_js( $theme_path . '/scripts/ajax_forms.js');
        break;
    case 'view':  // view pages (making this one up)
        drupal_add_js( $theme_path . '/scripts/fancybox.js');
        break;
}
// SWTICH BY CONTENT TYPE
switch($content_type){
    case 'services':
        drupal_add_js( $theme_path . '/scripts/fancybox.js');
        break;
}
// SWITCH BY NID
switch($nid){
    case '293': // Homepage
        drupal_add_js( $theme_path . '/js/global.js');
        break;
}
```

Right now I'm using `hook_node_view` to check content type & nid.  Works great for nodes, but doesn't help me with non-nodes.

Answer (score 1):

[`hook_entity_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/7) should do the trick

> Act on entities being assembled before rendering.

e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_entity_view($entity, $type, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  switch ($type) {
    case 'node':
      ...
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works on most pages, but is not firing on my entityform page.  I'm surprised - I don't see why this wouldn't work..

Comment: Yeah it won't work for forms as they're the 'edit' op instead of 'view'. `hook_form_alter()` might be your best option, you should be able to inspect the `$form` array and find out if has an entity attached (usually in `$form['#entity']`